# ScrollViewer cannot scroll down

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been doing a TextBlock inside a ScrollViewer but I cant seem to scroll down the ScrollViewer when the text inside the TextBlock is full. Below are my codes:

```
<ScrollViewer Canvas.Left="157" Canvas.Top="292"  Name="scrollViewer1" Width="362"Height="76">
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="157" Canvas.Top="292" Height="76" Name="totalIngredient" Text=""     Width="362" Background="#E6F8F2F2" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextBlock should fill the ScrollViewer completely, so set margin/width/height etc on the ScrollViewer instead. Also set horizontal scrollbar visibility to disabled, set vertical scrollbar visibility to auto (or whatever you want) and make the TextBlock wrap by setting TextWrapping to "Wrap":

```
<ScrollViewer Canvas.Left="157" Canvas.Top="292" Width="362" Height="76" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <TextBlock Name="totalIngredient" Background="#E6F8F2F2" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" TextWrapping="Wrap"  />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="76" Width="362">
    <TextBlock  Name="totalIngredient" Text=""  Background="#E6F8F2F2" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    </TextBlock>    
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: There are a lot of cases where this won't work as intended. If you place this code in a Grid (say) then the ScrollViewer will fill the entire Grid but the TextBlock will be the desired size. Apart from placing a huge border around the TextBlock the ScrollViewer will think it's got as much space as it needs and the vertical ScrollBar won't appear.